# Preventing pasting over data validation applied over multiple ranges (excel/VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So to preface this question, I'm a massive programming noob so any help would be appreciated. I have the following code that prevents the user copy and pasting over a range that has data validation applied to it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Does the validation range still have validation?
If HasValidation(Range("Section")) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
    " Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

However when I try to apply this to multiple columns (not just the named range "Section") it breaks. I tried creating a union and using that union as the range however that doesn't help either.

```
Private Sub Validationranges()
Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, Validationranges As Range
 Set r1 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Amort")
 Set r2 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Capcity")
 Set r3 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("ELV")
 Set r4 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Level")
 Set r5 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("ProcGrp")
 Set r6 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Region")
 Set r7 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Section")
 Set r8 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Tooling")

 Set Validationranges = Union(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call Validationranges
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("Validationranges")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
        " Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

If anyone could edit the code or suggest any other ideas that would be awesome, thanks.

Quick edit: not all columns are data validated, so alternating columns require exclusion from this rule.

Edit2: updated code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Does the validation range still have validation?
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, (Union(Range("Amort"), Range("Capacity"), Range("ELV"), Range("Level"), Range("ProcGrp"), Range("Region"), Range("Section"), Range("Tooling")))) Is Nothing Then
'if changes happen on the validation ranges then undo
    MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
    " Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you declare your variables as `Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, Validationranges As Range` you are declaring all of them as Variant apart from the last one which is a Range, you should declare them individually as `Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `If HasValidation(Validationranges) Then`?

Comment: Looking closer, am a little confused. Your variable `Validationranges` is declared in the first procedure and so is not known in the WorksheetChange event. In that code you have a named range "Validationranges" - how is that defined?

Comment: Tried the change @Xabier has suggested but am still getting Type mismatch error with 'Set r1 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Amort")'

Comment: @SJR he has also named his Sub the same as his variable, Aaron I think you should change this too.

Comment: Also you don't want `Set r1 = Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("Amort")`, it should be `Set r1 = Range("Amort")` but if you have a named range why create a range variable in addition.

Comment: @Xabier ok I've changed the sub to just Validation and the range object to validationranges, still have the type mismatch error though

Comment: Now getting range of object worksheet failed at 'Set r2 = Range("Capcity")'

Comment: I'm trying to combine multiple named ranges into one object as when I try to use multiple named ranges within the line:  'If HasValidation(Range("x, y, z")) Then' it doesn't work and breaks the functionality that previously worked when being implemented in just one named range.

Comment: This should work `If HasValidation(union(Range("x"),range("y"),range("z")))`

Comment: @SJR The code is functional with this change however it doesn't correctly identify validation anymore, the error input appears regardless of whether I copy and paste or use the correct method of input (the dropdowns). Likewise the error input appears in cells that don't have data validation applied.

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Union(Range("Amort"), Range("Capacity"), Range("ELV"), Range("Level"), Range("ProcGrp"), Range("Region"), Range("Section"), Range("Tooling"))) Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
        " Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: @Xabier The private function is the same as the original code

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, this will check if the value you entered is in the Data Validation List, if it is, then do nothing, if it isn't then Undo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range, r5 As Range, r6 As Range, r7 As Range, r8 As Range, ValidationRanges As Range
Set r1 = ws.Range("Amort")
Set r2 = ws.Range("Capcity")
Set r3 = ws.Range("ELV")
Set r4 = ws.Range("Level")
Set r5 = ws.Range("ProcGrp")
Set r6 = ws.Range("Region")
Set r7 = ws.Range("Section")
Set r8 = ws.Range("Tooling")

Set ValidationRanges = Union(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8)
If HasValidation(Target) Then 'check if cell has validation
ValidationList = Target.Validation.Formula1 'get list of values from data validation list
    If InStr(ValidationList, Target.Value) > 0 Then 'if value entered is in validation list
    'OK value
    Else 'if value entered is not in validation list then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, ValidationRanges) Is Nothing Then
        'if changes happen on the validation ranges then undo
            MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
            " Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

Comment: I get "application defined or object defined error" with `Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Range("Capcity")` using this code.

Comment: I tried: the code shown in the latest question edit, But get the error "requires an object"

Comment: I've updated my answer, simply amend the variable ws to reflect the sheet name you are using, I've tested this with Sheet1 and it works as expected.

Comment: Now got "Method range of object _worksheet failed", sorry to be such a pain, I have no idea what I'm doing >.<

Comment: @AaronGretton I get no such error, it works  when I'm testing, so it might have to do with some other factor that I'm not seeing, try setting your named ranges as `set r1 = Range("Amort")` without the `ws`? It is difficult to help when I'm not seeing what you are... :/

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid, work prevents screenshots/files being uploaded so can't give context. What causes this error to occur?

Comment: What is the scope of your named ranges? Do they all fail - looks like "Capcity" is a typo?

Comment: @SJR Capcity is not a typo as I recreated the ranges according to the OP's question, they seem to work for me as expected, but Aaron seems to be getting `Method range of object _worksheet failed`? Not sure what's happening...

Comment: @Xabier - yes I know that's what he posted but I think that error arises if the name doesn't exist and so wondering if it's actually called "Capacity".

Comment: Ahh... good point! @SJR, I didn't think that could be the issue... Let's see what the OP comes back with...

Comment: @SJR I'm officially a moron (also dyslexic) that did fix that problem, the code now runs however the error input still pops up when I try to choose something in a data validated column from a dropdown.
Edit: could this be to do with restrictions based on the dropdown themselves, i.e. does something have to be edited in the list that's prescribed to assign approved dropdown values?

Comment: @Aaron updated my answer so that if the value entered is in the Validation List it will accept the value, else it will undo.

Comment: @Xabier haha now it displays the input error, but afterwards displays the "has validation" notification, and still undoes it anyway. This is a lot more difficult than I thought it would be...

Comment: @AaronGretton sorry I left that line in for testing, I've just removed it, should work now, I hope... :)

Comment: @Xabier ok so the has validation popup doesn't occur but it still doesn't allow correct input in a data validated column from a dropdown, it still misfires the input error and undoes inputs from dropdown selection.

Comment: @Xabier How do you define the correct validation list for each separate column? Each column has its own accepted list of validated dropdown inputs, how do I make sure each column uses it's own applied list?

What does the formula1 part of `ValidationList = Target.Validation.Formula1` do?

Comment: I ask because I ask because It's still not accepting the dropdown selection - I can see how it works in theory but I don't know enough to know where things are going wrong. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @AaronGretton the line you wrote is to get the validation list from the given cell into a variable so that you can then check to see if Target.Value is within the list...

Comment: I'm beginning to think the code might be better being re-designed, this might help you: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2686-excel-drop-down-list-prevent-paste.html

Comment: @Xabier Ok, the linked code works fine, I apologise for wasting so much of your time, I really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronGretton you haven't wasted my time, hope I have been able to help or guide you a little... :)